# Convert an ordinal string to an integer with icu4j

Tags: java, ordinals, icu4j

I am attempting to convert an ordinal string, say "FOURTH" to integer 4. How can I accomplish this with the [*International Components for Unicode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) library for Java, [icu4j](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/)?

```
RuleBasedNumberFormat formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.US, RuleBasedNumberFormat.ORDINAL);

return formatter.parse("FOURTH").intValue();
```

Seems like this is not working, as 0 is being returned.
I'm expecting this to return 4.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use PluralRules. https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/PluralRules.html

Comment: For me, your code does not return `0`. It throws `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "FOURTH"`.

Comment: Interestingly, I found several existing questions that ask about integer to ordinal text, but this is the only Question I could find asking about the opposite, ordinal text to integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I read up on the [Javadoc documentation](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/) of [icu4j](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/) and the [`RuleBasedNumberFormat`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html) does not have FOURTH as a parsable string although it does support four. And instead of using [`RuleBasedNumberFormat.ORDINAL`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html#ORDINAL) uses [RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html#SPELLOUT).

```java
RuleBasedNumberFormat formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat( Locale.US , RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT );
try
{
    int result = formatter.parse( "FOURTH".toLowerCase( Locale.ROOT ) ).intValue();
    System.out.println( "result = " + result );
}
catch ( ParseException e )
{
    … add code to handle exception.
}
```

When run:

> 4

This is what the code should look like and make sure to use .toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) because parse does not work on upperCase strings.

Comment: Nice! A word of warning: This works for `THIRTY-THIRD` - but for `THIRTYTHIRD`, it incorrectly returns `30` (with no errors). So, this relies on hyphenation (and spelling, of course).